# Loud squealing noise in headphone/speaker followed by computer freezing

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Every so often when I move my MacBook Pro I get a loud squealing noise through the headphones/speakers and then it freezes.  After a forced reboot, everything is back to normal.

I looked in to the console to see if there could be anything related. Found a system report for a high memory water mark. In the system log, too, there is a bunch of abnormal code 126, and around the time the freeze up happens a few 255 and 110 codes. There are a lot of logs to go through and I have a screen recording of them all if that helps anyone.

Comment: When you move your MBP, is it a forceful move, such as picking it up from a desk, or sliding it across a flat surface (like a desk, for example;) or does it happen with both soft and forceful movements? Please edit your question, or add a comment, indicating the exact model of MBP you are using.

Answer (score 1):

> **Notice:** Although it seems unlikely it is possible there is a fault with the machine that could escalate, so if you haven't already please make sure to take a backup of your important documents.

There are a few things you could try:

1. Perform a PRAM reset by following Apple's instructions: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379
2. Perform an SMC reset by following Apple's instructions: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1543

***Test for a period***

3. Run Apple Hardware Test by following Apple's instructions, running the full/extended test: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201257

***Review the results for any obvious hardware faults***

4. Take a backup and reinstall macOS, I can provide instructions here if you get that far, but let's see the results of the hardware fault and screenshots, *you can add them to your original post as an edit*.